# is there python's as keyword in C#

Tags: python, c#, keyword

when i used python
i could replace library name using as keyword

this is an example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
plt.title("title")
plt.plot(a, label = 'maximum degree', color = 'cyan', linestyle=':', marker = 'v')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

according to this code
matplotlib.pyplot is replaced by 'as' keyword to plt

and i want use this keyword `as` in C#

- is there python's as keyword in C#

Comment: You can do something like: `using O = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;`

Comment: You have shown python, but no C#. This question is a little backwards

Comment: @MichaelRandall seems fine to me; "here's a thing I can do in Python (specific example); can I do that in C#?" - nothing backwards there

Comment: @MarcGravell definitely wont argue, but there was no reference. I mean what in C# was the op trying to `as` what problem did they have.

Answer (score 5):

in c#, "using alias"; if `matplotlib.pyplot` is a fully-qualified .NET type:

```cs
using plt = matplotlib.pyplot;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can alias your using namespaces/classes like this:

```cs
using NsJson = Newtonsoft.Json;


public void MyMethod(){

    new NsJson.Linq.JObject(); //example

}
```